# Factorial Recursive

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial

I'm trying to write an algorithm to calculate the factorial of a number using recursive function.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int n) {
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n*factorial(n - 1);
}
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cout << factorial(n);
    return 0;
}
```

It does nothing and I don't know why, it only lets me to give the number, but it's not calculating.

Comment: for a start, put the cin in main instead of the actual recursive function.

Comment: i fixed it,now it works,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `factorial` function you are waiting for another input which is not needed. Remove this `cin >> n;` from inside the `factorial` method.

Some other points which are not asked in the question:

- Factorials grow very fast and by using `int` you will quickly get an overflow. You may consider to use 64 bit `long long` instead.
- `conio.h` is not standard and should be avoided.
- Calling `using namespace std` in global scope is very bad.

Comment: 12! is the largest factorial that can be held in a 32-bit signed or unsigned `int`.

Comment: can you tell me why is bad to call using namespace std in global?

Comment: @MariAndrei Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: ... and you can't go very much further with 64-bit `int`, only to 20!

Comment: @WeatherVane yes but I guess using a 3rd party big number library at this stage will be difficult for OP.

Answer (score 1):

you initialised

```
n=0;
```

which doesn't taking input from you in main fn and calling factorial fn always with

```
factorial(0);
```

and also remove that cin>>n from fact fn and do something like

```
int factorial(int n)
{ if (n == 0)
   return 1;
   return n*factorial(n-1);
}

main()
 {
  cin>>n;
  cout<<factorial(n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program isn't doing nothing. It is doing what you do not expect. cin >> n should be in the main function, not in the factorial function.

What it is actually doing is placing each new number as a function call to factorial on the stack. Every time you re-input you're changing the terms of the factorial. For example, you input "4", and then "6", and then "8"... what you have on the stack is factorial(8) on top, then factorial(6), then factorial(4). Eventually you'll have to input "1" so that your program will end.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ask for user input inside factorial method. Do this instead

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n*factorial(n - 1);
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << factorial(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For large factorials, use floating point which supports exponential notation for numbers with a lot of 0s.

Also, what recursion does is push the numbers passed in number factorials to the stack and then return them once a function call finally returns, which is when it is 1.

For illustrative purposes, try this program.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int factorialtimes2(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n*factorialtimes2(n - 1)*2;
}

int main()
{
    cout << factorialtimes2(5) << endl;
    cout << 5 * (4 * 2)*(3 * 2)*(2 * 2)*(1 * 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```