# Factorial with recursion

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int fact(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Factorial:%ld\n",fact(n));
    return 0;
}


long int fact(int n)
 {
   if(n!=1)
   return n*fact(n-1);

    }
```

I'm trying to get the factorial of a number with recursion.But I'm getting 0 as the result everytime. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you return when `n` is 1?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#base_case

Comment: Remember to compile with all warnings on. If there are warnings think about why they're there.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the thing is that the same question was asked couple months ago or so, and the same exact question and the same exact solution.

Comment: @Gox The question in the linked post is a completely separate issue in a different language. There's nothing alike between the two.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just realized  I deleted the post, but believe me there was exact same question couple weeks ago :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial Recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223362/factorial-recursive)

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 That is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My bad; flag withdrawn. EDIT: s/flag/vote... maybe I shouldn't be doing this late at night.

Answer (score -1):

```
long int fact(int n)
{
    return n==1? 1 : n*fact(n-1);
}
```

Comment: `n` should be probably be `unsigned`, don't you think?